# How to implement RH SSO OpenID Connect (Keycloak) with Spring Boot app without having security constraints in the application

Tags: java, spring-boot, single-sign-on, openid-connect, keycloak

I am trying to configure the SSO OpenID Connect (Keycloak) on a Spring Boot application using access tokens only. I have set up the client in Keycloak for my app and configured the permissions and scopes. I want the application to interact with the Keycloak server to retrieve the user roles and authorizations from LDAP (or AD) groups based on the access tokens that will be passed with the requests under the "Authorization" header.

NOTE:
I found the java adapter (spring-boot-adapter) but it requires to specify the security constraints like roles, resources, etc. to be defined in the properties file. Following is the link to it:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_single_sign-on/7.2/html/securing_applications_and_services_guide/openid_connect_3#spring_boot_adapter

I also tried using the spring-security configuration and it requires to define the constraints while building routes using RestDSL. Something like this:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

Is there a workaround where I do not have to specify any kind of constraints in the application code and the Keycloak should handle all the authorizations based on the access token provided in the request?

Comment: When a request comes in, I want the spring application to make a call to Keycloak with the access token and then Keycloak should provide the authorization based on the permissions defined in it if the corresponding call is eligible for the response or simply return a 401 unauthorized response.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look about the Keycloak Gatekeeper Project? (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_keycloak_generic_adapter) 
There you can define Roles for Resources, etc. 
But it's an not a Spring Boot Application.

Comment: The need to define roles and resources in the configuration file is what I want to avoid since I already have these permissions defined in the Keycloak.